# CSV does not load to Google BigQuery

Tags: c#, .net, google-bigquery, google-cloud-storage

So I made a program that'll get the schema from a table in a MySQL Server, create a table based on the said schema, and insert the data rows which are saved in a  CSV file in a Google Cloud Storage.

---

Code for getting the schema from MySQL:

```cs
foreach (string table in listOfTableNames)
   {
      MySqlCommand query = new MySqlCommand($"desc {table}", openedMySQLConnection);
      MySqlDataReader reader = query.ExecuteReader();

      DataTable dt = new DataTable(table);
      dt.Load(reader);
      reader.Close();
      object[][] result = dt.AsEnumerable().Select(x => x.ItemArray).ToArray();
      TableSchemas.Add(table, result);
   }
```

---

Google BigQuery table maker from schema looped per table:

```cs
var schemaBuilder = new TableSchemaBuilder();
foreach (var column in dictionaryOfSchemas[myTablename])
{
   string columnType = column[1].ToString().ToLower();
   schemaBuilder.Add(
      column[0].ToString(),
      columnType.Contains("varchar") ? BigQueryDbType.String :
         (columnType.Contains("int") ? BigQueryDbType.Int64 :
         (columnType.Contains("decimal") ? BigQueryDbType.Float64 :
         (columnType.Contains("timestamp") ? BigQueryDbType.DateTime :
         (columnType.Contains("datetime") ? BigQueryDbType.DateTime :
         (columnType.Contains("date") ? BigQueryDbType.Date :
         BigQueryDbType.String)))))
   );
}
TableSchema schema = schemaBuilder.Build();
BigQueryTable newTable = bigquery.GetDataset(myDataset).CreateTable(myTablename, schema);
```

---

CSV to created GBQ table looped per table:

```cs
    bigquery.CreateLoadJob(
       $"gs://{myProjectIdString}/{myBucketNameString}/{myCSVFilename}",
       newTable.Reference,
       schema,
       new CreateLoadJobOptions()
       {
           SourceFormat = FileFormat.Csv,
           SkipLeadingRows = 1
       }
    ).PollUntilCompleted();
```

---

No error shows up after running the ***CreateLoadJob*** method.

Schema of the new table seems to be good and matches the CSV and the MySQL table:
[image: MySQL Schema]

Here's a sneak peak into the [CSV file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1-jLCDO1-hkQWyoDUFbxhrYRUtOQsJfKC/view?usp=sharing) in Cloud Storage with some data redacted out:
[image: csv preview]

But there's still no data in the table:
[image: BigQuery preview]

Am I doing something wrong? I'm still learning Google services so any help and insight would be appreciated. :)

Comment: Please could you post a [mcve] including a sample data file? (There's quite a lot I'd have to guess at in order to reproduce this.)

Comment: @JonSkeet, which sample file do you need clarification on? I tried to restructure the post to maybe explain what I did a bit better.

Comment: A sample CSV file would be a good start - and a *complete* example, rather than one that assumes there's already a `TableSchemas` property somewhere, along with a `config` etc. Basically I'd like code that I can copy/paste/run as far as possible, after just setting things like the project ID and dataset ID etc. (I can't see anything you've obviously done wrong, but being able to reproduce it with the same code as you would be the best starting point.)

Comment: @JonSkeet, I added more code and fixed some variable names and a link to a sample csv file. I hope that helps.

Comment: I've read somewhere that loading CSVs with CreateLoadJob() uses AutoDetect as True. Does this conflict with my custom defined schema?

Comment: Thanks for the CSV file. That's definitely helpful. This still isn't really reproducible though - why is MySQL involved at all, in a *minimal* reproduction? Just *hard-coding* the schema would be significantly better than that. In terms of what CreateLoadJob does - the .NET library doesn't specify it as true automatically, so the default is whatever would be server-side. If you could remove the MySQL code from your question and just create a hard-coded `TableSchemaBuilder` with the schema (there are only 8 columns, after all) that would make it much easier to try to reproduce.

Comment: I'll try to put together the kind of repro that I'm looking for, but it's generally much better for the person who's facing the problem to do so.

Comment: Okay, I've reproduced it now - see https://gist.github.com/jskeet/4147fa057838159587272d689a2fee93 for a genuinely complete example. (All you need is a console project with a reference to the BigQuery client library.) I probably won't be able to actually look into it today - it's the end of my working day now - but I'll look tomorrow.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few things wrong here, but it's mostly to do with the data rather than with the code itself.

In terms of code, when a job has completed, it may still have completed with errors. You can call [`ThrowOnAnyError()`](https://cloud.google.com/dotnet/docs/reference/Google.Cloud.BigQuery.V2/latest/Google.Cloud.BigQuery.V2.BigQueryJob#Google_Cloud_BigQuery_V2_BigQueryJob_ThrowOnAnyError) to observe that. You can get detailed errors via `job.Resource.Status.Errors`. (I believe the first of those detailed errors is the one in `job.Resource.Status.ErrorResults`.)

Once the correct storage URL is provided (which would be observed that way as well) you'll see errors like this, with the CSV file you provided:

> - Error while reading data, error message: CSV processing encountered too many errors, giving up. Rows: 1; errors: 1; max bad: 0; error percent: 0
> - Could not parse '06/12/2014' as DATE for field delivery_date (position 0) starting at location 95  with message 'Unable to parse'

At that point, the problem is in your CSV file. There are two issues here:

- The date format is expected to be ISO-8601, e.g. "2014-06-12" rather than "06/12/2014" for example
- The date/time format is expected to include seconds as well, so "2014-05-12 12:37:00" rather than "05/12/2014 12:37" for example

Hopefully you're able to run a preprocessing job to fix the data in your CSV file.

This is assuming that the schema you've created is correct, of course - we can't tell that from your post, but here's the schema that worked for me:

```cs
var schema = new TableSchemaBuilder
{
    { "delivery_date", BigQueryDbType.Date },
    { "delivery_hour", BigQueryDbType.Int64 },
    { "participant_id", BigQueryDbType.String },
    { "resource_id", BigQueryDbType.String },
    { "type_id", BigQueryDbType.String },
    { "price", BigQueryDbType.Numeric },
    { "date_posted", BigQueryDbType.DateTime },
    { "date_created", BigQueryDbType.DateTime }
}.Build();
```

Comment: Using the ThrowOnAnyError() is a godsend, i can finally debug this "magical" method lol.
Thank you very much! And yes, I did correct the weird data that my app is receiving.

Answer (score 0):

After fiddling with my variables and links, I figured out that making a link to your bucket folder should be **`gs://<bucket_name>/<csv_filename>`** instead of *`gs://<project_id>/<bucket_name>/<csv_filename>`*.
My code's running ok for now and successfully transferred data.

Comment: That's not the only problem though... I'm about to post an answer.